# Working from a german company in uk

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, part-time

I'm working for a German software company (I'm a German citizen), and plan to work from the UK for short periods of 2 weeks, for a total of 3-4 months/year due to personal reasons.

My company doesn't have an office in the UK, so I plan on working remotely from a home office. I'm also considering paying to rent office space.

What do I have to consider?

- Travel health insurance (already have 60 day coverage/per trip)
- Social insurance: As I keep my residence in Germany and stay here > 180 days this should not be an issue?

Edit:
I like to know if there are any restrictions by law, missing/mandatory insurances and formalities I have to take care of.

Comment: The most important question is if you are legally allowed to work in the UK. If so, do you have to pay them any taxes, or any such shenanigans? Make sure you are not violating the terms of your visa/stay while you're there.

Comment: @AndreiROM, He is. Brexit hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @stephanbranczyk - **"yet"** is so optimistic

Comment: Travel expenses? What they're willing to reimburse? Per diem amount? Corporate card? Have you read their employee manual?

Comment: I only have indirect knowledge, therefore I won't put it into answer, but somebody might use it as starting point. From german perspective you are considered a german employee as long as you don't stay abroad longer than 3 months at a different location in a row. A British colleague I had, had some restriction on the number of days he is allowed to work in Germany. Therefore I assume you are handled fully as a german employee if you stay under that limit.

Comment: @moatze: There is a downvote. I assume it's because you are asking an open-ended question with your bullet point list. I suggest to you to change it to something like "How can I ensure I'm treated like a german employee instead of a British one?"

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your comments so far. The disbursals are not part of my question, I edited my question to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Why should a company pay for you to work in the UK due to your personal reasons and not their reasons?

Comment: @EdHeal Why not? They invested into me for 3 years now, why lose this investment for something which costs them almost nothing?

Comment: Being out of the office over 25% time (let's not forget holidays) does cost. Unavailable for face to face. Meetings for a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need travel insurance, nor a visa, to work in the UK currently. We're still in the EU which means you'll be covered by the NHS as standard. Nobody knows what will happen when we leave, not even the people pushing Brexit through the pipeline currently.

> Social insurance: As I keep my residence in Germany and stay here > 180 days this should not be an issue?

Providing you don't naturalise in the UK you'll be fine - I'd definitely check with your local authority first to be sure though.

In terms of renting an office space - they're ridiculously expensive here in the UK. If you're staying for short bursts you'll struggle to find a place that will give a 2 week lease, let alone for a price that won't write off the majority of your income from work for that period.

You'd be better off finding a nice, short stay tenancy with a big room/office that you can work out of, or find a co-working space local to where you're intending to stay.

Comment: When we were looking to rent a small office rent, they were not too bad, but the charge for a telephone line and internet connection was more than the rent!

Answer (score 1):

Office rental might be expensive. The best deals on offices tend to be for longer (12 month+) durations and obviously the cost also varies dependent on location and facilities.

There are a number of companies (e.g. Regus) which offer semi-permanent or shared space or hotdesks, although that may be unsuitable if you have much more than a laptop (it's a nuisance having to setup kit every day and leads to breakages).

Also consider similar offerings from universities (no, really) as they tend to be a lot cheaper.

It really depends on the kind of work you're doing. I'd say your best bet would be a home office, at least for the first few weeks.